# Using R, for an unbalanced panel, count number of new individals that have been added in a given year and old individuals that have been dropped

Tags: r, panel

I have unbalanced panel data and would like to know how many new individuals are added an how many old individuals are removed in each year.
For example with the following data

```
Year <- c(2009, 2009, 2009, 2010, 2010, 2010)
ID <- c("A", "A", "B", "B", "D", "C")

df <- data.frame(Year, ID)
```

I would like to obtain:

| Year | Nr. Added | Nr. Removed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2009 | 2 | NA |
| 2010 | 2 | 1 |

```
structure(list(Year = c(2009, 2010), `Nr. Added` = c(2, 2), `Nr. Removed` = c(NA, 
1)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

The code below seems to work for identifying entirely new individuals, but not individuals that had disappeared and reappear. I also do not understand how I can generalize it to determine the individuals that have been dropped in a given year

```
y <- split(df$, arranged_data$year)

z<- data.frame(Year = names(y), nNew =
             diff(lengths(Reduce(union, y, NULL, accumulate = TRUE))))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit cumbersome, but works:

```
    # Group the data by year and store the unique individual identifiers for each year
    grouped_data <- with(df, split(ID, year))

    # Get the sorted unique years
    years <- sort(unique(df$year))

    # Initialize vectors to store the results
    individuals_added <- numeric(length(years))
    individuals_removed <- numeric(length(years))

    # Calculate individuals added and removed for each year 
    for (i in 2:length(years)) {
    individuals_previous_year <- grouped_data[[i-1]]
    individuals_current_year <- grouped_data[[i]]  
    individuals_added[i] <- sum(!individuals_current_year %in% individuals_previous_year)
    individuals_removed[i] <- sum(!individuals_previous_year %in%  individuals_current_year)}

    # Create a data frame with the results
    df <- data.frame(year = years[-1], individuals_added = individuals_added[-1], individuals_removed = individuals_removed[-1])
```